# Two block level elements 1 fixed width 1 stretch inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I have a table with multiple columns. In one of the column rows I want to add 2 elements which will be next to each other. One text element and one icon. The icon has a fixed with, the text element needs to be dynamic and has to be truncated with ... when the column cannot stretch anymore.

This is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>Truncated text goes here</span>
            <i class="icn sprite icn-name></i>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I do this? Using `display: table;` will make the HTML  all buggy.

Comment: Do you necessary have to use a table layout? There are a lot of ways to have a fixed width image and a variable width text.

Comment: Tried using float left and right with overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; and white-space: nowrap;. Also tried display: inline-block on both elements. And tried using display: table/table-cell; on the elements. The last solution has the best outcome, but the parent table is getting buggy when I do that.

Comment: Yes the HTML table is necessary, the display: table; etc is not.

Comment: And I also suppose that you don't want to separate image and text in 2 adiacent cells, right?

Comment: Every correct solution is welcome :) As long as the code stays semantically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `<i>` element in front of the `<span>` element and gave the `<i>` element a `float: right;` and the `<span>` element the truncate styles.

Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, if you allow text and image to stay in adiacent cells, you can try the following.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Truncated text goes here</td>
        <td><img src="imageURL" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can use `vertical-align:top;` in `td` style to align text on the top of the cell. And then you can use the following to set image width.

```
td>img {
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/duuLakhv/1/)

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to add extra cells to your table, you can create an internal `div` inside the cell, display it with `display:table;` property, and then display both `span` and `img` with `display:table-cell;` property.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/duuLakhv/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I thought you meant putting cells as child in the cell. I don't want any extra columns, because this wil mess with the text in my <th> tags. The left column will get wider, because the text in de <th> is probably wider than the text element in the column.

Comment: @NiekNijland: I've updated the answer to avoid adding extra-cells to layout. Let me know if it's ok now.

Comment: I found another solution! I moved the <i> element in front of the <span> element and gave the <i> element a float: right; and the <span> the truncate styles. It works perfect now! With your solution somehow the <i> element lost his width. I could not find out why:$

Comment: Thanks for your help btw! Appreciate it!